# React Native showing sequence PNG image as animation

Tags: react-native

I have this image which consists of all the frames of an animation
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeshifu/react-thanos/master/lib/assets/thanos_snap.png

Is there any way to show this image in React Native? I have been searching around but all other questions are about how to animate a list of images in sequence, but in my case it's just one image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the frames are all in one image file, so you probably want to render the image file once and translate the image inside a view that hides any overflow.

```
// Imagine 32 frames of 100x100 image. 
<View style={{ width: 100, height: 100, overflow: "hidden" }}>
    <Image style={{ width: 3200, height: 100, transform: [ { translateX: 0 } ] }} />
</View>
```

[React Native Transfrom docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/transforms#translatex)

You can set the `translateX` to `100 * i` to show the frame at index `i`.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I talked more about how to do it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56161161/3123335

Answer (score 1):

In this post I provided more information on how to achieve the desire result based on the great answer by @AJcodez.

So this is the necessary steps:

1. Calculate each frame size. In my case the image is 3840x80 and there are 48 frames, so each frame will be 80x80.
2. Initialize a state to hold the current frame index.
3. Setting `translateX` value to `-80 * currentFrameIndex` (because we will translate it from left to right).
4. Fire a `setInterval` to update the `currentFrameIndex` each X millisecond, and once the frame index gets to 48, we clear the interval and set the index back to 0.

This is the result:

[image]

You can view the code [here](https://gist.github.com/b1acKr0se/88af0467fda3bfd80e0311ea39cb5eef).

Comment: i don't think this will reliably create a smooth animation since it's having to communicate from the JS thread via the interval